# Responsive href different images for browser and mobile emails

Tags: responsive-design, html-email, email-templates

I am designing a mobile template. In that, Header is linked to the home page for the website. But the problem is there are two different headers for desktop and mobile. I want to link both the images to the home page of the website.Initially I tried

```
 .Header {
    width: 320px;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    background: url('Images/mobile.jpg') no-repeat;  
} 
.headerimg img {
    display: none !important;
}


<tr> 
        <td width="500"><a class="headerimg" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="Images/desktop.png" alt="Google" height="160" width="500" border="0" style="display:block;"></a></td>
    </tr>
```

Then I tried to do it placing two images size by size and hiding one based on the view

```
    .MobileHeaderImg {display: none !important;}
.HeaderImg {display: block !important;}
.HeaderImg a{display: block !important;}
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .MobileHeaderImg {
position: relative;
display: block !important;
width: 320px !important;
height: 100px !important;
}


<tr> 
  <td width="500"><a  href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="Images/header.png" class="HeaderImg" alt="" height="160" width="500" border="0" style="display:block;"></a><a class="headerimg" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="Images/mobile.png" class="MobileHeaderImg" alt="" height="160" width="500" border="0" style="display:block;"></a></td>
```

Any Idea
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Found a better solution. Added a <div class="name"> inside <a> and changed the bk image of div class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget where I picked this up from (somewhere in Email on Acid), but the below code should solve your issue. It will likely take some tweaking to fit into your template.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 500px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
        span[id=switcher] {display:block;
        background-image: url(http://www.emailonacid.com/images/blog_images/Emailology/2013/tablet.jpg) !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        background-position: center !important;
        width: 300px !important;
        height: 250px !important; }
        img[id=houdini] {display: none !important; }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 489px) {
        span[id=switcher] {display:block;
        background-image: url(http://www.emailonacid.com/images/blog_images/Emailology/2013/mobile.JPG) !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        background-position: center !important;
        width: 300px !important;
        height: 250px !important; }
        img[id=houdini] {display: none !important; }
    }
</style>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.emailonacid.com"><span id="switcher"><img id="houdini" src="http://www.emailonacid.com/images/blog_images/Emailology/2013/Desktop.jpg" alt=""></span></a>
</body>
```